# Undefined variable error when using jQuery datepicker and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, datepicker

How do I copy the `datepicker` date into the PHP variable, `$adateStringValue`?

When I use  " `$adateStringValue = $_POST['datepicker'];` " I get `Undefined variable: adateStringValue error`. How do I rectify this problem?

The following is my code.

To select a date:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#datepicker").datepicker({
     dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"   
     });
$('form#dateform').submit(function(){   
  var aselectedDate = $('#datepicker').val();
  localStorage.setItem('adate', aselectedDate);
  });
});
</script>
```

abc.php :

```
<?php
 echo "<form id=\"dateform\" name=\"dateform\" action=\"associate.php\" method=\"POST\"><br><br>
 <table>
 <tr><td>
 <b>Select date<b></td><td>
 <input id=\"datepicker\" name=\"datepicker\"value=\"$adateStringValue\"/>
 </td></tr>
 </table>
?>
```

I need to check this selected date with a column in the database( this column has dates in the string format).

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$sql1="SELECT event_date from events_schedule";
$getDates_query= mysql_query($sql1,$con);
$adateStringValue = $_GET['datepicker']; 
while($fetchdates = mysql_fetch_array($getDates_query)) {
   if ($fetchdates['event_date'] == $adateStringValue) {
     $message = "You have selected this date";
     echo "<script>alert('$message');</script>";
    }
      else {
      $message1 = "Select another date";
      echo "<script>alert('$message1');</script>";
       }
     }
  }
```

The complete code is as follows:

```
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#datepicker").datepicker({
   dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"   
 });
$('form#dateform').submit(function(){   
 var aselectedDate = $('#datepicker').val();
 localStorage.setItem('adate', aselectedDate);
  });
});
</script>

<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","" );
if(!$con){
die("Cannot connect:" .mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("trainingschedule",$con);
echo "<form id=\"dateform\" name=\"dateform\" action=\"associate.php\"method=\"POST\"><br><br>
<table>

<tr><td>
<b>Select a date &nbsp;&nbsp;<b></td><td><input id=\"datepicker\" name=\"datepicker\" size=\"15\"    value=\"$adateStringValue \"  /></td></tr>
</table>
<br>
<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\"/>;
</form>";

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$sql1="SELECT event_date from events_schedule";
$getDates_query= mysql_query($sql1,$con);
$adateStringValue = $_POST['datepicker']; 
while($fetchdates = mysql_fetch_array($getDates_query)) {
 if ($fetchdates['event_date'] == $adateStringValue) {
 $message = "You have selected this date";
 echo "<script>alert('$message');</script>";
}
else {
 $message1 = "Select another date";
 echo "<script>alert('$message1');</script>";
  }
 }
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: form method is post, try $_POST['name']

Comment: @RayonDabre I tried using POST.. It didn't solve the problem.

Comment: You're missing a space between the `name` and `value` attributes on your datepicker.

Comment: `<input id=\"datepicker\" name=\"datepicker\" value=\"$adateStringValue\"/>` This line should be like this..You can not have `<?php` inside echo. You need to use **IDE**

Comment: You are also not closing your string at the end of the file. Add `";` after `</table>'.

Comment: Reread what Rayon is saying. You're trying to get the value of the POSTed data using the $_GET array. Change _GET to _POST on this line `$adateStringValue = $_GET['datepicker'];`

Comment: In most databases, you can directly choose the data type "datetime" which is usually displayed as "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss", which again is derived from a UNIX timestamp.

Therefore, I highly recommend using "yy-mm-dd" in your datepicker.

Comment: Also if that is all of the code in abc.php, where do you set $adateStringValue in that script? If you only set the variable when the page has been posted to than it will not be set. You need to do this `$adateStringValue = "";` immediately before your check for the if isset _post submit

Comment: @Terminus Sorry.. The whole code is in the same file. Changing GET to POST didn't solve the problem. When I check the value of adateStringValue using an alert, the alert pops up with nothing getting displayed.

Comment: Post your code exactly as you have it please. And take a look at my comment right before your comment

Comment: In your "full code" you are now missing a space between the `action` and `method` attributes on your form...

Comment: @Pot-Nut. No offense. ..But does the "space" really matter?

Comment: @newbie Probably not, but it is invalid (X)HTML. I am going to add an answer that seems to work fine for me. You need to declare `$adateStringValue` to be something _before_ it is used.

Answer (score 1):

Change your PHP to the following so that you are declaring `$adateStringValue` *before* it is used. Adjust accordingly to add your MySQL logic back in:

```
<?php

// Ternary IF statement to set either the $_POST value or a blank string
$adateStringValue = (isset($_POST['datepicker'])) ? $_POST['datepicker'] : '';

// Just use a blank action attribute to POST to the same file.
// Also added a space between the action/method attributes to output valid (X)HTML
echo '
      <form id="dateform" name="dateform" action="" method="POST"><br><br>
          <table>
              <tr>
                  <td><b>Select a date &nbsp;&nbsp;<b></td>
                  <td><input id="datepicker" name="datepicker" size="15" value="' . $adateStringValue . '"/></td>
              </tr>
          </table>
          <br>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
      </form>
     ';

// Output the value if we have POST data
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $message = "You have selected this date: $adateStringValue";
    echo "<script>alert('$message');</script>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id='datetimepicker1' >
<input type='text' class="form-control" name="datatime" data-date-format="MM/DD/YYYY" />
<span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
</span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question